# Execute php script random with cron Job

Tags: php, apache, cron

I need to execute a php script 4 times a day.

1º between 8:00 and 9:00 am

2º between 11:00 and 12:00

3º between 13:00 and  14:00 pm

4º between 18:00 and 19:00 pm

With cronjobs its possible to do this, but how?

My server is Apache 2.4.12 and PHP 5.4.37.

The php script is for seek news in certain feeds, i already done the php script.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: Not yet, i was trying to analyze how.

I thought about making 4 cron tasks for this, but I have no idea what would be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use curl to call the URL then on your crontab:

```
0 8,11,13,18 * * * curl -s http://localhost/${phpscript}
```

Of course replace ${phpscript} with the path to the PHP script you want to run. You can even run phpscript on command line.

Comment: `curl` may not work if the file is outside the web root.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ probably I've been confused by the "Apache ${version}". Of course if php script is out of apache scope you will need to run with php-cli (if it is installed)

Answer (score 1):

In your `crontab`, put these commands.

```
# Seek news in certain news feeds.
30 8 * * * php -f /path/to/script.php
30 11 * * * php -f /path/to/script.php
30 13 * * * php -f /path/to/script.php
30 18 * * * php -f /path/to/script.php
```

It will trigger PHP to parse and execute the file `/path/to/script.php` between the hours 8, 11, 13, 18.

To install `crontab` read this article: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

On the command line, put `crontab -e` to edit/add cron jobs.

Comment: Nice, lets say now i need to fill some news database, but need to be in random time i.e between 8:00 and 9:00 am? It can not be "exactly" 8:00 every day, its need to be between 8:00 and 9:00 AM.

Comment: @LincesMarques randomly inbetween? Or a set minute?